# Why doesn't iPhone's Safari trigger changed event on input type=file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

There is an iPhone and need to catch `change` event on a hidden input. When opened at PC, it works, I see `changed` text. In case I open it on an iPhone it doesn't work as expected, I just see `open dialog`.

Simple [jsfiddle demonstrates this](https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/qdmtvLct/).

```
<input type=file style="display:none" id=file>
<button type=button id=but>open</button>

<div id=out>
</div>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#but').on('click touchend', function(){
    $('#out').text('open dialog'); 
    $('#file').click();
  });
  $('#file').on('change', function(evt) {
    $('#out').text('changed');
  });
});
```

What's wrong with it? Is it a new bug of iOs? Afaik, it worked just a month ago.

I tried to replace `hidden` with `opacity:0`, it works for simple jsfiddle, but doesn't work in complex project with hiding sidebar. The question is the following. How to make a simple fix and what has changed recently (some Safari update?), that caused the change of hidden input behaviour?

Comment: Try removing the display:none css styling, if it works try opacity:0 instead, the css maybe preventing the action ( i believe in the past this was an issue )

Comment: Hm. The trick works for Safari and for Chrome at iPhone5S. What the byte is this?

Comment: Are you running this in the Iphone browers or in something like webview of android? If I understand you right you want that people can upload a file? But that doesn't happend it doesn't open the file manger? I am right or I am understandig it wrong?

Comment: It was Safari browser. Right, I wanna have an ajax upload.

Comment: It is hard for me to reproduce this situation since all my iOS work just fine with your code. What iOS version are you using? And have you thought about putting the input file element on top of your button, giving is `opactity:0;` and make the size the same as the button? That trick should always work.

Comment: @hallleron Does the fiddle work well for you?

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you add anything?

Comment: why is the opacity:0 option not good for you?
you can also do "position: absolute;"  and "left: 999999em" and it will act the way you want

Comment: @KingpinEX `opacity:0` works in a simple fiddle but doesn't work in my sidebar upload. I'll try to make another fiddle to represent it if it is possible.

Comment: Yes the fiddle worked good. If you have a better fiddle to illustrate your problem, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `for` property of `label`.
the following code may be helpful for you:

```js
$('#file').on('change', function () {
  $('.button').text('changed')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' style='display:none' id='file'>
<label for='file' class='button'>open</label>
```

using `label`, you can use custom style for your upload button

However, in some mobile browsers, when you upload file again, if the file is same with before, it won't trigger `change` event, you use `reset` method of `form` to clear file:

```js
 $('#file').on('change', function () {
      $('.form')[0].reset()
      $('.button').text('changed')
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='form'>
  <input type='file' style='display:none' id='file'>
    <label for='file' class='button'>open</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Fantastic. It works. I've just changed `<a>` with `label` tag and I see `changed` event. But why?

Comment: Works for both, Chrome and Safari. Thanks.