# change event and files property not updated by particular files selected with Photo Library

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-video-input

On iOS(v11.4) Safari and Chrome the file input's "change" event and `files` property are not updated by selecting file:

https://afblob.blob.core.windows.net/test/IMG_6599.mp4

with "Photo Library" but will update with file:

https://afblob.blob.core.windows.net/test/mov_bbb.mp4

and others. All files work however when selecting the files with "Browse". I noticed a flash of a progress bar that says "Compressing video..." when using the "Photo Library" and selecting the files that fail to update the input but no error message, as if the os is silently failing to compress the video and not giving a file to the browser. I'v tried a simple `<input type="file" />` without JavaScript, the JavaScript in the example above it just to demonstrate.

The issues [Why doesn't iPhone's Safari trigger changed event on input type=file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724477/why-doesnt-iphones-safari-trigger-changed-event-on-input-type-file) and [javascript file input onchange not working [ios safari only]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664777/javascript-file-input-onchange-not-working-ios-safari-only) do not help. The input element is added directly to the dom and the user is clicking directly.

What about the file causes the issue? Is this an iOS/Photo Library bug?

note: This is important because to our users it has the same behavior as successfully selecting a video but our app does not respond because it waits for the "change" event and even if we got around that the `files` property of the input does not reflect.

Comment: I was able to confirm this bug this bug in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on iOS 11.4 (15F79). Did you report it to apple? https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: No, I don't have a developer account.

Comment: Made bug report, problemID 41726507