# Input event on file type not firing in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, safari

I am uploading a file using AJAX and jQuery. It is working well in Chrome and Firefox but the problem I am getting is in Safari. I tried to debug this but the debugger did not stop when I upload the file.

```
<input type="file" class="file_input" name="myfile"/>
```

```js
$(document).on('input', '.file_input', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("userfile", this.files[0]);
  showLoader();

  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': _token
    },
    url: base_url + "controller/action",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      that.closest('tr').find('.document').empty();
      hideLoader();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors, and add an `error` handler and check it's output in Safari. You can debug from there.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724477/why-doesnt-iphones-safari-trigger-changed-event-on-input-type-file

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nothing on console actually it is not going to that line of script.

Comment: Can you post some CSS style also?

Comment: @DanielSmith input is not hidden

Comment: @DanielSmith no css simple `html5` tag

Comment: Try using the `change` event instead of `input`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually dont you think the question text was precise. because if in future someone could easily get that by typing input click event on file in safar. Ajax file upload is itself a very vast and broad topic. Just a suggestion!

Comment: Yes, you're right regarding the title, I changed it back. Did you try changing to a `change` event? `input` is usually defined as being triggered by data entry, not a selection hence why the `change` event is more commonly used on file inputs

Comment: yes i am testing the change event .

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah it works with the change event but i dont know the reason why input did not work on safari.

Comment: It's a known issue: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event. `4. Doesn't fire an input event when (un)checking a checkbox or radio button, or when changing the selected file(s) of an <input type="file">. See Chrome bug, WebKit bug, and Firefox bug.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your guidance. Can you please put an answer so that in future people can easily get help from it.

Comment: Sure, I added it for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari does not support the `input` event on `file` input elements:

> (Safari and some other browsers) don't fire an input event when (un)checking a checkbox or radio button, or when changing the selected file(s) of an . See Chrome bug, WebKit bug, and Firefox bug

> https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event

To fix this you can use the more widely supported `change` event instead:

```
$(document).on('change', '.file_input', function() {
  // your code...
});
```

---

***- 2020 Update -***

This issue in Safari was fixed in version 13.1, released in March 2020. To be clear, any version of Safari since then now supports the `input` event on a `file` input.

If you have a requirement to support legacy versions of Safari, then you will still need to use the `change` event, as outlined in my original answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set accept attribute on your input. So the best course of action here is maybe to add both MIMEs and extensions on inputs.

```
<input
    type="file"
    id="attachments" 
    accept="application/msword,image/gif,image/jpeg,application/pdf,image/png,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/zip,.doc,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.pdf,.png,.xls,.xlsx,.zip" 
    name="myfile"
    class="file_input"
>
```